# Best WPF text control for dynamic styling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, localization

I am trying to localize a WPF application, but am running into a problem with formatting. Say you have the following:

```
<Run>Text</Run>
<Bold>Emphasis</Bold>
<Run>Rest</Run>
```

I need a way to dynamically create this. Is there a good control for this?

**Additional Reasoning**

Different languages could have emphasis in different places and result in bold being first, or there being 4 total inlines, thus why I would like to have one localized string like this:

```
Text <Bold>Emphasis</Bold> Rest
```